# display custom fields in coocommerce my-address.php file

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

i'm using a plugin to add some custom fields to the checkout page also display them in my-account page the plugin works perfectely but i need now to add a field to my-address.php template bellow is my code :

```
echo $custom_user_meta = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), '_billing_mr_ou_mme', true);
```

this code is not displaying anything i'm sur that the meta name of my custom field is _billing_mr_ou_mme but nothing is displaying 
but when i do :
  `echo $custom_user_meta = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'billing_phone', true);`
the code works, so my code is not working only with the custom fields but works with the defaut woocommerce fields, can any one help 
the name of the plugin is : https://wordpress.org/plugins/flexible-checkout-fields/

Comment: Have you checked the database and associated table to see if the metakey 
does effectively exist and contains a value?

Comment: yes it exist because in my-address.php page all this data are displayed but in one <address></address> tag so there not well styled

Comment: @7uc1f3r the support of the plugin told me to do : echo $order->get_meta( ‘_billing_mr_ou_mme’); to display the field but i'm in the address template not the order template

Comment: `$order->get_meta(..` is not the same as `get_user_meta(..` 
but would be equivalent to `get_post_meta(..`